# Store python array in each entry of a column

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, multidimensional-array

I have got an array 'mutlilabel' which looks like this:

```
       [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  ...
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

and want to store each of those arrays in my target variable as I am facing a multi-label classification task. How can I achieve that? My code:

```
pd.DataFrame(multilabel)
```

Outputs multiple columns:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7

0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you saying you just want the dataframe to have a single column with arrays of length 8 as each value in the column?

Comment: exactly! I want this as my target variable for a neural network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(multilabel))
list_column = df.apply(lambda row: row.values, axis=1)
pd.DataFrame(list_column, columns=['list_column'])
```

Result df:[image]

Comment: But you don't need to change your multilabel list of lists to a df to train your NN.

Comment: Can I just pass it? I am new to NN and especially to the Huggingface library with its Dataset objects. I have to do the train_test_split like splitting it into train_data and test_data and not the x_train/x_test/y_train/y_test structure. Thats why I want to transfer that multilabel list into a dataframe structure...

Comment: from sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split:
"Allowed inputs are lists, numpy arrays, scipy-sparse matrices or pandas dataframes."

Answer (score 1):

Have you consider using the following trick?

```py
import pandas as pd

arr =  [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

pd.DataFrame([arr]).T
```

Output

```
                          0
0  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2  [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
3  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
4  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

**EDIT**
In case you are using `numpy` arrays you can use the following

```py
import numpy as np

pd.DataFrame(np.array(arr))\
  .apply(lambda x: np.array(x), axis=1)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me! It just transposes my 8x1026 array into a dataframe od 1024x8

Comment: Don't forget the extra set of square brackets around around `arr` in `DataFrame([arr])`; those turn it into a three-dimensional nested list, so the DataFrame is forced to pick two and leave the third one as lists

Comment: @JiříBaum was this for me or for @soulwreckedyouth?

Comment: That was @soulwreckedyouth, sorry

Comment: Yeah! Those brackets just throw the following error: ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 1026, 8)

Comment: But they throw an error with my example or with your real data?

Comment: Probably the data is in a numpy array, rather than a python list of lists; that gives exactly this error

Comment: Thank Jiri. @soulwreckedyouth as future reference try to ask question using these resources [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) [mcve](/help/mcve). If in your question you use lists instead of numpy arrays people try to answer using the same format of data you provided.

Comment: sorry for that. will do that in the future

Answer (score 1):

So, the real question is why... it doesn't seem like the most useful data structure.

That said, the one-dimensional data type in pandas is the `Series`:

```
>>> pd.Series(multilabel)
0    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2    [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
3    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
4    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
dtype: object
```

You can then convert it further into a DataFrame:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(multilabel))
                          0
0  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2  [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
3  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
4  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

**Edit:** Per further discussion, this works if `multilabel` is a nested Python list, but not if it's a NumPy array.